# Pass data from jQuery to PHP file in one set

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a table and some `<td>` have a data, but not all of them. On a button click I run jQuery function which checks each `<td>` and where the data is present, grabs the data.
After that the data is being passed to php file and inserted into my DB. Everything works great.

```js
function insert_data() {
  if(confirm("\nAre you sure?.\n")) {
    $("#myTable td").each( function() {
      var worker = $(this).attr("id");
      var quarter = $(this).attr("title");
      var station = $(this).attr("name");
      var type = $(this).attr("class");
      $.post({ url: "insert_data.php", data: {worker:worker, quarter:quarter, station:station, type:type} });
    });
  }
  else { return false; }
}
```

I am wondering if instead of calling the php with ajax for every `<td>`, maybe there is a way to pass the data like one package? I checked at least couple dozen different articles here and on other websites and it seems that very often JSON is used for that purpose.
I've never worked with JSON and after several days of trying different approaches, still can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I will appreciate any help.
All I need is to pass data from my table into php file (and unpack it in there). I do not need to display it simultaneously on the html page.

Here is one of the versions which doesn't work:

JS:

```js
function insert_data() {
  if(confirm("\nAre you sure?.\n")) {
    var myArray = []; // var to store all records for json data transfer
    $("#myTable td").each( function() {
      var worker = $(this).attr("id");
      var quarter = $(this).attr("title");
      var station = $(this).attr("name");
      var type = $(this).attr("class");
      var record = {worker:worker, quarter:quarter, station:station, type:type}; // sd - short for schedule data
      myArray.push(record); // add every record to same array
    });
      console.log(myArray);
      $.post({ url: "insert_data.php", data: {myArray: myArray }, success: function(data){ alert('Items added'); }, error: function(e){ console.log(e.message); } });
  }
  else { return false; }
}
```

In console I see following data (it looks like the data is being added to the array without issues):

```
(4) [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]
0: {worker: "556", quarter: "1", station: "abc_15", type: "rework"}
1: {worker: "147", quarter: "2", station: "abc_37", type: "rework"}
2: {worker: "345", quarter: "3", station: "abc_15", type: "rework"}
3: {worker: "12", quarter: "4", station: "abc_15", type: "rework"}
```

PHP:

```
  $mySchedule = array();
  $mySchedule[] = $_POST["myArray"];  // get the json array
  var_dump($mySchedule);
  foreach ($mySchedule as $sched) {
    $worker = $sched['worker']; // or: $sched->worker; - doesn't change the result
    $quarter = $sched['quarter'];
    $station = $sched['station'];
    $type = $sched['type'];
    // code to insert data into my DB - works fine when I pass data one by one instead of array
  }
```

HTML:
I also added this script to the page with my table:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-json/2.6.0/jquery.json.min.js"></script>
```

I am not sure if it is needed or not.

--
It feels that the problem is in the way how I "unpack" the array. But I am not sure... I tried to follow all advises I could find here, but maybe I just miss something really important.
I tried:

```
$mySchedule[] = json_decode($_POST["myArray"]); // in insert_data.php

data:  { json: JSON.stringify(myArray) } // in jQuery function
```

and some other advises...

Comment: You can pass an array of data from web page to php, which you are doing successfully, but you cannot insert multiple records in database (from an array) so you have to loop through and insert one record at a time. In mySQL you can write one long sql query, seperated by comma, that can insert multiple records.

Comment: Why the foreach loop is not good for that? I was sure it does the same job as a regular loop. I use mySQL insert statement inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Can you verify if the data makes it to your PHP script successfully?  It seems like this will be a DB insert issue.

Comment: I don't want to look like a complete noob (even if I am), but how can I check if the data actually makes it to the php file? In the console I see: "jquery.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8000/insert_data.php".". If I just open the php, it looks like: array(1) { [0]=> NULL }

Comment: the var_dump($mySchedule); should print your data

Comment: Nawed Khan - I have it in my code, but it shows only: array(1) { [0]=> NULL } .

Comment: When you use the `data:  { json: JSON.stringify(myArray) }` approach, what do you get if you `print_r($_POST['json']);`?

Comment: I will check tomorrow as soon as I will get to my code. Thank you for an idea.

Comment: Nick, it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### update

I got some help from one of my colleges. So, the jQuery code stayed without changes. PHP code had couple minor changes and it works fine now.  The changes in PHP:

```
$mySchedule = $_POST["myArray"];  // get the json array
```

instead of:

```
$mySchedule = array();
$mySchedule[] = $_POST["myArray"];  // get the json array
```

That is it. Thank you very much for help and advises. I hope this example will be helpful to others.